# Error in REST Web Service to receive and upload video to server using a iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, rest, wcf-data-services

I need to add an upload video feature to my iOS app. That said, I am using a WCF service but it seems that is not working, the file is uploaded but the video is trowing an error.
This is my code from my IOS app:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
    NSLog(@"got a movie");
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dotstudioservices.com/labajaService/Service1.svc/videoempresa"]];
    [request addValue:@"video" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSInputStream *inputStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:[videoURL path]];
    [request setHTTPBodyStream:inputStream];

    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"Request ended");
         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
         }
         else if (error != nil){
             NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
         }
     }];
}
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; }
```

And this is my code of the WCF service:

```
public Status FileUploadVideo(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1000000);

        FileStream f = new FileStream("D:\\Hosting\\9692238\\html\\promosbc\\videoslabaja\\video.mp4", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        f.Close();
        stream.Close();
        return new Status { status = "done" };
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#creating-an-upload-task-for-a-multi-part-request-with-progress

Comment: but what about the server side?

Comment: I'm afraid no one will help you without something from your side, we don't just provide code for everyone. Besides, this is too broad as there are many languages to handle these uploads so go pick a language then do some research and tutorials then come back with what you have tried and tag your question. :) You learn and it helps everyone. Usually one builds the web service first before you start with an app?

Comment: I tried a lot of approaches before come here but they didnt work but to this point i am desperate, but i will put the code of the WCF Service that was using.

Comment: So it should be in WCF or will PHP be fine?